# Date Format: Apex Callout (Soap webservice)

Tags: apex, callout, soap, date, formatting

We are performing an apex callout from Salesforce to a SOAP based webservice and it requires us to pass a date in the following format: MM/DD/YYYY (note: this should be date datatype). When I am passing the Salesforce date field directly, it's passing the value as 2017-12-06 00:00:00.

If I try to format the date using format() method, it's returning the value in required format but in String datatype. How can I send the value in MM/DD/YYYY format and also retain the datatype of the value as Date ?

Comment: This service expects the parameter to be an xsd:date, correct?

Comment: Also, perhaps you might [edit] in some code to see what you've tried so far? It's kind of hard to predict much when we have to guess. Also, the relevant parts of your wsdl, if you don't mind. The more info we have, the better.

Comment: @sfdcfox
You are right. It says "Date" and it expects the value as 12/6/2017

Comment: @sfdcfox
Actually there is no much code. I am simply passing Salesforce Date field value in the request and it won't accept it because of the formatting. If I make the format using Datetime.format(), then the value would be String datatype. Don't know how to format and retain the value of the datatype as date

Comment: the xsd:date format doesn't allow that date format. Meaning if they expect it, they are not SOAP compliant. At minimum, they need to support CCYY-MM-DD, as stated in the XML specification of xsd:date.

Comment: @SFDC_BigDog Can you share the WSDL of the target web service? Or at least the parts around the problem date.